# Change image source but then image doesnt appear

Tags: javascript

I got this code online and wanted to change the image source from an online picture, to the one i have on my root folder. But everytime i change the file location, image doesnt appear.

```
var firstreel=new reelslideshow({
    wrapperid: "myreel", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [1310, 400], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["http://i30.tinypic.com/531q3n.jpg"], //["image_path", "optional_link", "optional_target"]
        ["http://i29.tinypic.com/xp3hns.jpg", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave", "_new"],
        ["http://i30.tinypic.com/531q3n.jpg"],
        ["http://i31.tinypic.com/119w28m.jpg"] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your image path you are setting?

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong...

Comment: var firstreel=new reelslideshow({
 wrapperid: "myreel", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
 dimensions: [1310, 400], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
 imagearray: [
  ["C:\Users\Rizal\Desktop\Project AMBIENT\Photos\b.jpg"], //["image_path", "optional_link", "optional_target"]
  ["http://i29.tinypic.com/xp3hns.jpg", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave", "_new"],
  ["http://i30.tinypic.com/531q3n.jpg"],
  ["http://i31.tinypic.com/119w28m.jpg"] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
 ],

Comment: program is running but just the image not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it to a folder without spaces in its path or replace the spaces in your path with %20 (url encoded space char)

If the html / js is palced inside your "Project AMBIENT" folder you dont have to use the full path. You can use "./Photos/xyz.ext" or depends on where the files are placed "../Photos/xyz.ext"

Answer (score 0):

try using `file:///C:\Users\Rizal\Desktop\Project_AMBIENT\Photos\b.jpg`

you will have to properly escape the whitespace in `Project Ambient` or rename it to `Project_AMBIENT` or something like that.

[File URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

**Update**

Put the following in a file called "img_form.html" and double click it:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="target" action="javascript:return false;">
  <input type="text" value="http://i30.tinypic.com/531q3n.jpg" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<br>
<img id="image"/>

<script>
$('#target').submit(function() {
  $('#image').attr('src', $("input:first").val());
});    
</script>
</body>
```

Now change the text in the input form to some local url:

Unix:

```
file:///Users/snies/Pictures/043.jpg
```

Windows:

```
file://localhost/c:/some/folder/foo.jpg
file:///c:/some/folder/foo.jpg
```

and press the button.

Comment: Thanks. Did the following but unable to resolve.

Comment: try my example code above, and report on the result

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a local file path:

```
C:\Users\Rizal\Desktop\Project AMBIENT\Photos\b.jpg
```

you have to use a file that is hosted on a web server:

```
www.x.com/images/stuff.jpg
```

Comment: actually you can, just try it